# File Not found exception

Tags: java, filenotfoundexception

I have a bunch of files in a folder checked out from a repository. I have a code which has to copy the files from the folder to another folder. I do the following:

```
File f = new File(/* path of folder */);
File[] fs = f.listFiles();
for(int i=0; i<fs.length; i++){
        FileChannel in = new FileInputStream(fs[i]).getChannel();
        FileChannel out = new FileOutputStream(/* output directory */ +File.separatorChar+files[i].getName()).getChannel();
        in.transferTo(0, in.size(), out);
}
```

However, the .svn file within the checked out directory is causing a problem. I get the exception:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /checked_out_folder/.svn (No such file or directory)
[x]     at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
[x]     at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:120)
```

Is it because it is a hidden file? What could be the solution for this? Or am I missing something here?
Thanks

Comment: exclude the svn with if statement

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it is because it is a directory and not a file.

Directories you have to create by using the [mkdir](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdir%28%29) method. Whole directories cannot be copied in java as far as I know.

For an example on how to copy a directoy, see [this](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-copy-directory-in-java/) blog post.

Comment: Is there a way I can prevent copying hidden files/directories?

Comment: @user682765: why not simply check if it's a directory first?

Comment: Check out Attributes.readDosFileAttributes if you're using java7 to detect hidden files.

Comment: as i was telling you in my answer, this is a directory. the problem is not with the beeing hidden but with beeing a directory. when looping over the files, you need to check it it is a directory, then perform a recursive deep copy of that directoy. see [this](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-copy-directory-in-java/) blog post on how to copy directories.